# Conditionally load a different set of factories in Angular based on environment

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular application which has two different types of backend; one which is used when the application is loaded via a normal web page and one which is used inside a Cordova application.  The purpose of this is so that the rest of the application just knows it gets the services and only the services are specific to storing data on the client or on the server via AJAX.

Obviously I could do this using a symlink or something that I change before loading, but I'd really like to just set it up so I can use a different environment config and have it load the other set of services.

Each service will have two versions, one for "http backend" and one for "mobile backend". Both versions will either extend the same abstract base class or implement the same interface.

Perhaps most importantly, the application should not load the code for the unused set of services, so just having the code decide which service to return won't suffice.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// service used in components/other services
export class DataService<T> {
  constructor(
    private connectionService: ConnectionService,
    private crudService: CrudService,
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private store: Store<AppState>) {}
}
```

then you can provide different implementations on module level:

```
const FirebaseProviders = [
  { provide: AuthService, useClass: FirebaseAuthService },
  { provide: ConnectionService, useClass: FirebaseConnectionService },
  { provide: CrudService, useClass: FirebaseCrudService },
  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: FirebaseErrorHandler, deps: [DataService, Store] },
  { provide: StorageService, useClass: FirebaseStorageService },
];

const MockProviders = [
  { provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService },
  { provide: ConnectionService, useClass: MockConnectionService },
  { provide: CrudService, useClass: MockCrudService },
  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler, deps: [Store] },
  { provide: StorageService, useClass: StorageService },
];

const CoreProviders = environment.production ? FirebaseProviders : MockProviders;

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...CoreProviders,
    DataService
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Make sure to list all dependencies in

```
{ provide: <ServiceA>, useClass: <ServiceB>, deps: [<IMPORTANT for AoT>] }
```

or you will get nasty (hard to debug) AoT error.

Comment: I should have clarified in the question; it's not enough to just load the right set of providers, the size of the providers is not insignificant so I need it to not load the code for both sets -- I probably need either lazy loading or some method tied to the default build tools so that it does not load the AJAX providers when it needs the cordova ones and particularly so it never loads the cordova providers when it is a normal website.

Comment: I use CLI which does tree-shaking in production builds. For example when I use `const DEV_MODULES = environment.production ? [] : [DevModule]` and import `DEV_MODULES`, bundle size is **+15.93KB** in development mode and **+80B** in production. You can setup your AjaxModule/CordovaModule and load them based on environment...

Comment: If you want single build for both cases, you can use lazy loading and setup your providers there.

Comment: Awesome; I'll try it out, but this sounds like the answer I need. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any gotchas for making tree-shaking work? I've tried this and it so far puts both in regardless of the parameters in my environment that I'm checking on